# Verbo VENIRE nel discorso indiretto

Tags: verbs, grammar

Quando dobbiamo  cambiare 'venire' in 'andare' e quali sono le altre caratteristiche di utilizzo del verbo 'venire' nel discorso indiretto??? 
Grazie mille in anticipo!

Comment: Benvenuta/o su Italian.SE!

Comment: Ciao, @Milena Dagueva, «caratteristiche» è un parola femminile, quindi l’articolo è «le» (le altre caratteristiche). Poi, dopo «utilizzo» usiamo la preposizione «di» (utilizzo del verbo «venire»)

Comment: So quanto è difficile questo uso :-) Mentre penso a una risposta più completa, considera che «andare» si usa in modo “generico” (es. Mi ha detto che andrà al cinema da solo); invece «venire» si usa per dire «andare dove si trova, sta per andare o andrà la persona che parla o a cui si parla» (es. Mi ha detto che sarebbe venuto al cinema con me).

Answer (score 1):

La regola è spiegata nel libro *Nuovo Espresso 3. Corso di italiano* (livello B1) di Maria Balì e Luciana Ciglio in un modo molto simile a quanto l'ha fatto Benedetta nel suo commento:

> **Andare**, nel discorso indiretto, significa andare in un posto qualunque, **venire**
>   invece significa andare nel posto dove si trova, dove sta per andare o dove 
>   andrà la persona che parla o a cui si parla.

Questo libro riporta l'esempio che segue.

**Discorso diretto: trascrizione di una chiamata telefonica:**

(tratta dalla "guida per l'insegnante", nel "libro dello studente" veramente si tratta di un audio in un DVD)

> ■ Pronto, studio Moretti.
>   
>   ● Buonasera, mi passa il Dottor Moretti per favore.
>   
>   ■ Chi lo desidera?
>   
>   ● Sono l’ingegner Magistri. 
>   ■ Ah, buonasera ingegnere.
>   
>   ● Buonasera.
>   
>   ■ Senta, il Dottor Moretti è impegnato sull’altra linea. Vuole che la faccio richiamare?
>   
>   ● No, non importa. Gli dica che oggi non mi sento bene, quindi non posso venire all’appuntamento. Se per il Dottore 
>   va bene, però, può venire lui a casa mia: sono libero dalle cinque alle sette.
>   
>   ■ Ah, va bene, glielo dico io.
>   
>   ● La ringrazio.

**Discorso indiretto: messaggio della segretaria al Dottor Moretti:**

> Ha chiamato l'Ingegner Magistri. Ha detto che oggi non si sente bene, quindi non può **venire** all'appuntamento. Ha detto anche che se vuole però può **andare** Lei a casa sua: è libero dalle cinque alle sette.

Si scrive "non può venire all'appuntamento" perché si fa riferimento al luogo dove si trova l'Ingegner Magistri, che è quello che legge il messaggio. Si dice invece "può andare Lei a casa sua" perché in questo caso si fa riferimento a casa dell'Ingegner Magistri, posto dove non si trova il lettore del messaggio.

Ecco altri esempi che appaiono in questo libro:

> L’avvocato ha detto che Lei può 
>   **andare** all’appuntamento. 
>   Buongiorno Architetto, l’Ingegner 
>   Marini ha detto che non può **venire** 
>   all’appuntamento. (cioè nel luogo 
>   dove si trova l’Architetto)

Altri esempi in cui si cambia "venire" nel discorso diretto in "andare" nel discorso indiretto tratti di questo stesso libro:

**Discorso diretto: un messaggio SMS:**

> Ciao Roberto, 
>   Oggi non posso venire a giocare a tennis con te. [...]

**Discorso indiretto:**

> Giulio ha scritto a Roberto che oggi non **può andare** a giocare a tennis con lui. [...]

**Discorso diretto: messaggi su una chat:**

> **Pierlugi cell** 
>   [...] Stasera io e Paola andiamo da Federica. 
>  
>  
>   **Federica** 
>   Se vuoi venire a cena a casa mia, mi devi chiamare entro le 7.

**Discorso indiretto:**

> Perluiggi ha creato un gruppo su una chat e [...]. Voleva avvertirla che stasera lui e Paola **vanno** da Federica. Anche Federica ha scritto a Elena. Le ha detto che se vuole **andare** a cena a casa sua, [...].

**Discorso diretto: una mail:**

> Ciao Carlo, ho letto su *Facebook* che vieni a Napoli per lavoro la prossima settimana. [...]

**Discorso indiretto:**

> Anna ha letto su *Facebook* che Carlo *va* a Napoli per lavoro la prossima settimana. Così gli ha scritto una mail per [...].

Comment: Per i miei gusti (e non solo miei), questi esempi eccedono nell'uso delle maiuscole. Il dottore, l'ingegnere e l'architetto sicuramente non le meritano. Al limite se ne può parlare per qualche Re/re o Papa/papa. Poi, il “Lei” di cortesia suona un po' troppo ricercato (soprattutto considerando che in “la faccio richiamare” non c'è).

Comment: (Infine, io direi “Vuole che la facci**a** richiamare?”, ma forse è una cosa mia.)

Comment: D'accodo, @DaG, ma è così come appaiono nel libro citato.

Comment: Certo, @Charo, non criticavo te: aggiungevo una chiosa al testo citato.

Comment: Non so, @DaG, forse dovremmo dire alla [Scuola Ufficiale di Lingue di Barcellona](https://www.eoibd.cat/ca/idiomes/italia/llibres-i-lectures) che usano libri cattivi per i loro corsi d'italiano :(

Comment: Grazie, @Charo! Pensavo proprio a Nuovo Espresso 3, che ho usato per insegnare e che però purtroppo non ho ora con me. Se non ricordo male, nel libro dovrebbero esserci anche esempi con il tu.

Comment: Hai ragione, @Benedetta: ci sono più esempi in un esercizio. Dopo gli aggiungerò alla risposta.

Comment: Grazie! Vediamo se la risposta è sufficiente.